# Clearing results from a function and/or reupdate results

Tags: javascript

I have a button that will activate a function but whenever i click the button, more results will appear from the function. I wish that the results will be updated / cleared so that i can update it with new results. Below is my code.

```
    function getManeuver(){
 var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+document.getElementById('origin-input').value+"&destination="+document.getElementById('destination-input').value+"&key=MYAPIISHERE";
  $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
  console.log('success',data); 
 drawTable(data);

}
});

function drawTable(data) {
 for (var i = 0; i < data.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
    drawRow(data.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i]);
  }

 }

function drawRow(steps) {
 var row = $("<tr />")
 $("#personDataTable").append(row); 

     row.append($("<td>" + steps.maneuver + "</td>"));
}

  }
setInterval(getManeuver, 5000);
```

The results will be as shown

```
undefined
turn-right
undefined
turn-left
turn-right
turn-left
undefined
turn-left
```

but it will keep repeating and relisting instead of updating / clearing.

Comment: i would help that it can reupdate the results instead of cleaning

Answer (score 0):

If by result you mean the table.
you need to clean the previews result from the table.

$("#personDataTable").html("");

Comment: is there a way for me to reupdate instead of cleaning?

Comment: why are you using a table and not just div/span and then just update him?